# facebook api weekly total reach

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-insights

I am trying to get the weekly total reach for a facebook page through the API.
I am using the graph api with the method /insights/page_impressions_unique/day/
the title and description of this method according to the api are:
"title": "Daily Total Reach",
"description": "Daily The number of people who have seen any content associated with your Page. (Unique Users)"

But when i compare the results with the insight of the page (web version) the results do not match (when i add up the results from the api for the same dates).

am i looking at the wrong metric?

thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? Also wondering, are you using the API in php, or another language?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the Facebook isn't counting only unique users? Have you tried removing "_unique" from the API call.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#page_impressions